# converting list of floats to a set of values

Tags: python, pandas

Question 1 : Can we convert list of float values to sets

DATA :

```
A   B
1   [1212.0, 2121.0, 323.0]
2   [2222.0, 2222.0, 323.0]
3   [3232.0, 2323.0, 323.0]

dtype(B) = object
```

Expected output:

```
A   B
1   {121, 2121, 323}
2   {2222, 2222, 323}
3   {3232, 2323,323}
```

Question 2 :

I have a dataframe where I am merging the clusters with songs, in cluster one if there is a null value, it should ignore that and consider only the values which have numbers.

Data :

```
cluster songs
1   11
2   22
1   22
2   
3   22
1   
3   11
4
```

Output :

```
cluster songs
1   [11,  22, ]
2   [22, ]
3   [22,11]
4   []
```

Expected output :

```
cluster songs
    1   [11,  22]
    2   [22]
    3   [22,11]
    4   []
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `list comprehension`:

```
df.B = df.B.apply(lambda x: [int(i) for i in x])
```

Or:

```
df.B = [[int(i) for i in x] for x in df.B]

print (df)
   A                  B
0  1  [1212, 2121, 323]
1  2  [2222, 2222, 323]
2  3  [3232, 2323, 323]
```

---

For sets:

```
df.B = df.B.apply(lambda x: set([int(i) for i in x]))
```

---

```
df.B = [set([int(i) for i in x]) for x in df.B]

print (df)
   A                  B
0  1  {2121, 323, 1212}
1  2        {323, 2222}
2  3  {3232, 323, 2323}
```

But if need only convert to `set`s:

```
df.B = df.B.apply(set)
print (df)
   A                        B
0  1  {2121.0, 323.0, 1212.0}
1  2          {323.0, 2222.0}
2  3  {3232.0, 323.0, 2323.0}
```

For another question use:

```
uniq = df['cluster'].unique()
df = df.dropna(subset=['songs'])
df.songs = df.songs.astype(int)
df = df.groupby('cluster')['songs'].apply(list).reindex(uniq, fill_value=[])
print (df)
cluster
1    [11, 22]
2        [22]
3    [22, 11]
4          []
Name: songs, dtype: object
```

Comment: hey there is a question no 2 as well ;p

Comment: @jez...AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'apply'

Comment: its <class 'list'>

Comment: B    object
dtype: object

Comment: But your error `'function' object has no attribute 'apply' ` means you have some naming problem, e.g. some function is called `df` or something similar. Try use `df`, `df1`... for DataFrames. I think problem should be in your real code.  Now I am going to dinner, but maybe you can send me your real code to my email from my profile and I can check it.

Comment: sure ..iill check and let you know